# Why is this generic method with type constraint not compiling?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, compilation

I would like to know why the generic method below does not compile (C# 4.0). Neither my colleagues nor me can figure it out.

The compiler complains that `this` which is a `SelectableRowBase` cannot be converted to a `TItem` which is constrained to derive from `SelectableRowBase`. If I put an explicit cast everything works (and that is what I checked in source control), but I would like to know why the compiler is complaining here.

Is that a compiler error? Am I missing something?

```cs
public class SelectableRowBase
{
    public void AddToSelectedListWhenIsSelectedChanges<TItem>
            (ObservableCollection<TItem> selectedList)

        where TItem : SelectableRowBase
    {
        // Causes error:
        // The best overloaded method match for 
        //     'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<TItem>.Add(TItem)'
        //      has some invalid arguments
        // Argument 1: cannot convert from SelectableRowBase' to 'TItem'
        Action actionOnSelected = () => selectedList.Add(this);
        Action actionOnDeselected = () => selectedList.Remove(this);

        // Compiles and works fine
        // only difference is the explicit cast
        Action actionOnSelected = () => selectedList.Add((TItem)this);
        Action actionOnDeselected = () => selectedList.Remove((TItem)this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's entirely reasonable for it not to work.

You're trying to add an instance of a *base* type to a collection of a potential *derived* type.

That's like trying to write:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
strings.Add(new object());
```

That would violate type safety.

Basically, there's absolutely no guarantee that `this` is an instance of `TItem`. It *might* be which is why the cast compiles - but equally it might not be. That cast is a *really bad idea* - it's leaving type safety to execution time, which is the opposite of the purpose of generics.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I knew it would be related to type safety (I read both Eric Lippert's and your blogs). Somehow because in that specific case it was a collection of the right type I could not think of the more general case of somebody using it in the wrong way. I need to go back to the drawing board to prevent somebody from using this in the wrong way.